# Ending up with four screens on my laptop display - can't do anything

Tags: laptop, screen, asus, split

Just got a new ASUS laptop and every things good with it for the most part.

But when I booted from a Ubuntu USB, I believe it was 14.04.3 or later, before the logo even loaded I was left with two side by side screens.  Logo appears (loading ubuntu logo), I hit esc read the commands, I have two screens of commands.  Ubuntu loads, I have to ubuntus, this is all on my 17" ASUS laptop screen.

This is such an odd thing, I didn't even try to go any further with installation.  And I totally dismissed the idea of even putting it on the computer til I realized I have this account… anyway ideas, suggestions, comments, please.

I'm pretty sure this isn't going to have any resolve at least with this version of ubuntu, here are the photos of what I'm referring to.

There's really a total of four screens I end up with after it loads.

[image: two screens then they multiply to four]
[image: just the lines prior to everything breaking in two]
[image: managed to get settings pulled up-no monitor listed]

**update**
visit https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI, which states some hardware may not function properly in uefi mode

I turned on legacy mode by disabling secure boot, enabling csm changing a couple other bios settings to allow to boot from legacy... Booted in legacy mode and ended up with a single screen.

unfortunately I'm trying to install an operating system in dual boot mode with windows 10 (uefi mode), so this really isn't any help but still may be important to note that: I receive a black screen when ubuntu loads. By black I mean as if screen is off.

after following the instructions provided below, I wanted to test the graphics card prime and the drivers under ubuntu.  the initial boot command worked like a charm.  but the drivers-or shall I say wine crashed when trying to run World of Warcraft.  I ended with this message:

fixme:d3d:resource_check_usage Unhandled usage flags 0x8.
blah@blah:/media/blah/Wireless Duo/Blizzard/World of Warcraft$ err:winediag:xrandr12_init_modes Broken NVIDIA RandR detected, falling back to RandR 1.0. Please consider using the Nouveau driver instead.
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:process:GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx (3,(nil),0x33ef54): stub

Comment: first of all for newer hardware I'd suggest to use newer ubuntu release 15.10 or 16.04. If disabling UEFI solves your screen problem then you should proceed the installation in that way. Just before to do that, login into your windows and reduce the size of your windows file system by leaving whatever space you want to allocate to linux and install ubuntu over that free space. For the issue with your blank screen, it is not really clear to me if you either meant that blank screen appears in uefi or non-uefi mode, if you can be a little more clear there maybe we can go further.

Comment: If youre going to downtalk or be rude I guess askubuntu will accept that but I wont.

Comment: @daniel, would you boot in legacy and try `nomodeset` as stated in this solution https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: I would but due to my windows 10 installation in ufei that method is not suggested by ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely seems to be a graphics drivers related compatibility issue.
You say that you have a new ASUS laptop ... ASUS ships with NVIDIA cards.
As you didn't provide further details, I assume it came with GTX 900 series.
For these new adapters it is recommended to use the latest official drivers.

Boot from Ubuntu USB installation media you have created.
Highlight Try Ubuntu without installing - press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Now add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu Live desktop.

Install Ubuntu - when finished - install the NVIDIA drivers.

Boot the computer and when the GRUB menu appears ...
Highlight the Ubuntu menu entry and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the linux line.
Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key to boot into the Ubuntu system.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
Enter your user name and the password and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

Notes :

After the drivers are installed adding a boot parameter isn't necessary anymore.
Check whether you have to enable NVIDIA graphics or switchable mode in BIOS.
Install Ubuntu in the same mode as Windows, so select the USB entry with UEFI.
Should there occur problems with nouveau.modeset=0, use nomodeset instead.
Use NVIDIA X Server Settings to switch between intel and NVIDIA graphics card.

USB :

In case no UEFI USB entry is offered in BIOS, create a new installation media.
Use the diskpart tool, open command prompt as administrator and execute :

```
diskpart
list disk  
select disk *  
clean  
create partition primary  
active  
format fs=fat32 (quick)  
assign letter=**
```

Note : * = number of USB drive | ** = select a free drive letter.
Mount Ubuntu ISO file and copy the content to the USB drive.

Comment: This sounds promising, yes it is gtx970m.  Thanks for the response i will try it today/tonight

Comment: Well the command line entry after linux i. Grub allowed me to boot properly.  After selecting install alongside windows and mistakenly letting ubuntu do the work, upon reboot I was thrown into a bash command line.

Comment: Worked around that momentarily to test out the 358 drivers and prime, and award the reputation if things work out.

Comment: ALMOST good, please read my edit

Comment: @daniel : The Wine crash seems to be WOW related - but most important : I am very glad that you've got Ubuntu and the NVIDIA drivers installed properly and that the main operating system is running without the problems you described in your question ! When you install Ubuntu the next time, I recommend that you select "Something else" instead of "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" and do everything manually. :)

Comment: Well the other errors seem to be topics for another thread, unfortunately it appears I cant reward you for the answer any longer.  But Im on my phone maybe from a computer I can.